# How to check programmatically if the connection is slow (100% Loss/Very bad network) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how to detect a slow internet connection in Swift. I already know how to detect if the user is *connected* or not, but not specifically if the connection is bad or not. I would like to know this because I think my app has been rejected by apple connect review because of this.

Here's my code:

```
    public class ReachabilityTest {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)

    }

}
```

I would be glad to know if someone can help me out.

Comment: Run a ping service - look a the delays. Apple has an example project.

Comment: @DavidH hi, thank you for your answer. but can you please elaborate or give me the link of that project because I can't find it ;( and I don't understand how can this help me to detect a bad connection?

Comment: SimplePing. Look for drops - no returns - and for replies you get keep track of the delay. High ping loss or erratic delays give you useful info.

Comment: @DavidH Could you please provide a link to apple's example project?

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger seriously? Did you search on “SimplePing” in Google? Comes right up. Links break as Apple moves things.